# PHP equivalent to Java gmtFormat

Tags: java, php, timezone

I have to connect with a API to validate an ID. The example they gave me is in JAVA and I need to pass the date time in the same format as in the example. I am trying to convert the same in PHP. I have tried a few things but it is not working.
The sample JAVA code

```
Date datetimeNow = new Date();
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
String RequestDate = gmtFormat.format(datetimeNow);
```

What I have done is

```
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$timestamp = time();
$req_date = gmdate("D, d F Y H:i:s z", $timestamp);
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: `M` instead of `F`, for starters.

Comment: Also, whoever decided that was a good format to send a date through an API doesn't deserve your business, to be frank.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I can't help that. That is how I need to pass. I have also tried contacting them for help but they don't even help. They are just saying to append time zone short code. Like PST, IST, EST etc

Comment: Then (in addition to my first comment) `e`, not `z`.

Comment: But really, you should read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) which is pretty clear about what is what.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have read some parts of the doc. I will give that a try. Thank you for your help. I will let you know if that helped.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I believe that is RFC 1123 / RFC 822 . Not the worst of choices. Of course [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) would be a better one.